# Are answers that discuss design/architecture related aspects of an on-scope question valid?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-answer

On [IsInternetAvailable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115649/isinternetavailable), I've written an answer ([IsInternetAvailable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115649/isinternetavailable/115671#115671)) that addresses more high-level issues with the code from my perspective.

From what I can tell from the help center, questions that are about such a high-level review are not considered in the scope. How about answers that address such points, even though they weren't put up for consideration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reviewers are always free to voice concerns about *any & all aspects of the code* - and since *the code is the design*, the design is always somewhat implicitly up for review as well.

We ask that *reviewees* post their actual implementation, because "any & all aspects of the code" includes more than *just the high-level design*, so an asker posting a hypothetical implementation that's really just presenting a design, in such a way that really only the design is up for review, would be off-topic.

However if a reviewee posts their completed design (through their working code) and you come along and see design flaws, just like if a reviewer comes along and sees a bug that the OP missed, then that's when OP possibly gets the most out of CR!

---

**TL;DR:** These restrictions are for questions, to make sure the code posted is in a reviewable state - answers don't have these restrictions.